# Redshift SQL statement that will return 1 or 0 if the select statement returns any rows

Tags: sql, select, case, amazon-redshift

I have the following select statement in Redshift that will return rows with certain values if the condition inside is met. I want to transform this into a DQ check which will return 1 (True) if no rows ae returned or 0 if any row is returned, but I do not know where I should apply the case statement.
Here is the select statement:

```
 select * from (select brand,calendar_dt, product,
 count(account) count from revenue_base 
 where player_days = 0 and volume_loc >0 group by brand,calendar_dt, product) 
 where count > 1000 and calendar_dt >='2020-07-12'
 and calendar_dt < '2020-07-13'
```

Can you please offer me some ideas for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Redshift supports booleans, so `case` is not needed.  Second, do the filtering on the date *before* the aggregation.  This is usually faster.

Then, you can filter by the count using a `having` clause, so no subquery is needed:

```
select not exists (select 1
                   from revenue_base 
                   where player_days = 0 and volume_loc > 0 and
                         calendar_dt >= '2020-07-12' and calendar_dt < '2020-07-13'
                   group by brand, calendar_dt, product
                   having count(*) > 1000
                  ) as result
```

Comment: Note that your query is _not_ the same as the OP, because you filter then aggregate, rather than vice-versa.  It may be what the OP intended though.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . It should return the same results.  `calendar_dt` is a `group by` key, so filtering afterwards and before has the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using exists logic here:

```
select
    case when not exists (
        select 1 from
        (
            select brand, calendar_dt, product, count(account) as count
            from revenue_base 
            where player_days = 0 and volume_loc > 0
            group by brand, calendar_dt, product
        ) t
        where calendar_dt >= '2020-07-12' and calendar_dt < '2020-07-13' and
              count > 1000
    )
         then 1 else 0 end as result;
```